# Create fields on website based on data from active directory c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, active-directory

I have made a c# website I generate buttons, links based on the groups the user is a member of from active directory.

This will happen in the load event making the application very slow in the startup. How can I speed up this process?

Comment: I don't think you can get around doing it in the Load event - you need to know before the page is displayed. But can you update your question with the code you have now? We may be able to suggest some performance improvements.

Comment: Hi again,
I am querying Active Directory and 20 security groups like this.

Comment: GroupPrincipal grpXX = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.Name, "LL_xx"); foreach (Principal p in grpAqua.GetMembers(true)) based on environment.username I do something